# Group Array Data PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array...

```
[0] => Array
(
  [Name] => Steve Richard
  [Car_Colour] => Red
)

[1] => Array
(
  [Name] => Scott Lucas
  [Car_Colour] => Orange
)

[2] => Array
(
  [Name] => Danny Sisum
  [Car_Colour] => Red
)

[3] => Array
(
  [Name] => Alice Small
  [Car_Colour] => Green
)
```

How do I output the data in the array, but group the data by Car Colour, so the people with the two red cars will appear underneath a header of red, and the others for Orange and green?

**Example:**

```
People with **Red** cars

    Name:** Steve Richard
    Car Colour:** Red

    Name:** Danny Sisum
    Car Colour: Red

People with **Orange** cars

    Name:** Scott Lucas
    Car Colour:** Orange

People with **Green** cars

    Name:** Alice Small
    Car Colour:** Green
```

Comment: Just curious, are you retrieving this data from a database and using PDO?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$array = array(
        "0" => Array("Name" => "Steve Richard","Car_Colour" => "Red"),
        "1" => Array("Name" => "Scott Lucas","Car_Colour" => "Orange"),
        "2" => Array("Name" => "Danny Sisum","Car_Colour" => "Red"),
        "3" => Array("Name" => "Alice Small","Car_Colour" => "Green"));

$list = array();
foreach($array as $data)
{
    $list[$data['Car_Colour']][] = $data;
}

var_dump($list);
```

To Display them like above

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach($list as $color => $data)
{
    printf("People with **%s** cars\n",$color);

    foreach($data as $info)
    {
        printf("\tName:** %s\n",$info['Name']);
        printf("\t Car Colour:** %s\n",$info['Car_Colour']);
    }
    print(PHP_EOL);
}
```

Output

```
People with **Red** cars
    Name:** Steve Richard
     Car Colour:** Red
    Name:** Danny Sisum
     Car Colour:** Red

People with **Orange** cars
    Name:** Scott Lucas
     Car Colour:** Orange

People with **Green** cars
    Name:** Alice Small
     Car Colour:** Green
```

Comment: @Malovich looks like the fastest to me ...  `array_reduce` can also work

Comment: It will throw errors (warnings) about trying to use null as an array.

Comment: $list[$data['Car_Colour']][] = $data;

The first time you try to $list['green'][] = 'nipples' $list['green'] is not an array, php should throw a warning... i think.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(); // The array you currently have
// Grouping
$grouped = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $colour = $item['Car_Colour'];
    if (!isset($grouped[$colour])) {
        $grouped[$colour] = array();
    }
    $grouped[$colour][] = $item['Name'];
}
// Output
$output = '';
foreach ($grouped as $colour => $names) {
    $output .= 'People with **' . $colour . '** cars' . "\n\n";
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $output .= "\t" . 'Name:** ' . $name . "\n";
        $output .= "\t" . 'Car Colour:** ' . $colour . "\n";
    }
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$grouped_array = array();
foreach($array as $person){
   if(!isset($grouped_array[$person['car_colour'])){
         $grouped_array[$person['car_colour']] = array();
   }
   $grouped_array[$person['car_colour'][] = $person['name']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_color = array();  // This line is only truly neccessary if $arr_data can be empty
foreach ($arr_data as $arr) 
    $arr_color[$arr["Car_Colour"]][] = $arr["Name"];

// Display
foreach ($arr_color as $color => $lst_persons) {
    echo "<p>People with *** $color *** cars</p>";
    foreach ($lst_persons as $person) {
        echo "Name: " . $person . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Input:

```
  $arr_data = array(
  0 => array(
         "Name" => "Steve Richard",
         "Car_Colour" => "Red"
       ),
  1 => array(
         "Name" => "Scott Lucas",
         "Car_Colour" => "Orange"
       ),
  2 => array(
         "Name" => "Danny Sisum",
         "Car_Colour" => "Red"
       ),
  3 => array(
         "Name" => "Alice Small",
         "Car_Colour" => "Green"
       )
  );
```

Output:

```
People with *** Red *** cars
Name: Steve Richard
Name: Danny Sisum

People with *** Orange *** cars
Name: Scott Lucas

People with *** Green *** cars
Name: Alice Small
```

Comment: can't assume $arr_color['green'] is an array.

Comment: @Rick Burgess: I don't think I am assuming that - I am deliberately creating a list (array) per color.

Comment: Perhaps i'm wrong... i would have thought that trying to use $var['test'][] on an nonexistent array item would throw a PHP warning, however two people yourself and Baba don't agree so I guess i got that wrong.

Comment: I see your point.  Yes, that's why I like php!  You can do that in php, I am so used to doing it that I have forgotten how strange it is.

Comment: @Rick Burgess: In fact, you don't even need to define `$arr_color = array()` for my code to work.

Comment: are you sure, even with E_ALL?


I really must let this go :)

Comment: @RickBurgess: Just tested it - no errors thrown in php 5.3.0 after setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Awesome, back in my box I go :)

Comment: It pays to make sure of stuff like this!